# Switching ContentViews Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom navigation Bar. I have set up my Navigation Bar and called it `NavBar`, and added a ContentView above it containing the Current Displayed page. I have created a public variable containing the ContentView like so: `public ContentView CurrentPage = new Featured();` and I have a StackLayout set up in the Page like so:

```
var stacklayout = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
stacklayout.Children.Add(CurrentPage);
stacklayout.Children.Add(NavBar);
Content = stacklayout;
```

I have a function that is called when a button on my NavBar is pressed to change the value of CurrentPage, set up like this:

```
void NavToBuy(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentPage = new Buy();
}
```

But when the button is pressed, nothing happens. I think that the value is being changed, but not displayed on the screen. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was taken from reddit user brminnick1

> You need to replace `CurrentPage` inside of the StackLayout, which would
>   look something like this:
>
> ```
> Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => stackLayout.Children[0] = new Buy());
> ```